# grab all numeric data in final two columns, the position of which varies by rows

Tags: r, data.table

I have a sample data as follows:

```
dt1 <- setDT(structure(list(V1 = c(301L, 301L, 301L, 301L, 301L), V2 = 1:5, 
    V3 = c(61950L, 61951L, 61953L, 155220L, 155218L), V4 = c("i", 
    "you", "you", "we", "they"), V5 = c("believe", "think", "are", 
    "laugh", "smile"), V6 = c("we", "they", "okay", "490", "490"
    ), V7 = c("can", "500", "with", "31", "31"), V8 = c("use", 
    "32", "that", "", ""), V9 = c("datatable", "", "500", "", 
    ""), V10 = c("always", "", "32", "", ""), V11 = c("500", 
    "", "", "", ""), V12 = c("32", "", "", "", "")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", 
"V12"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame"))

   V1 V2     V3   V4      V5   V6   V7   V8        V9    V10 V11 V12
1: 301  1  61950    i believe   we  can  use datatable always 500  32
2: 301  2  61951  you   think they  500   32                         
3: 301  3  61953  you     are okay with that       500     32        
4: 301  4 155220   we   laugh  490   31                              
5: 301  5 155218 they   smile  490   31
```

I want it to convert to something like below:

```
    V1 V2     V3                               newcol1 newcol2 newcol3
1: 301  1  61950 I believe we can use datatable always     500      32
2: 301  2  61951                        you think they     500      32
3: 301  3  61953                you are okay with that     500      32
4: 301  4 155220                              we laugh     490      31
5: 301  5 155218                            they smile     490      31
```

**Mechanism:**

- a) Columns V1,V2, and V3 in sample data are always numeric and will
  remain the same in sample output
- b) the final two columns in sample 
  data are always number but the position of final two columns differs for each row: in the sample data above, row 1 has V11 and V12 as final columns, row2 has V7 and V8 as final two columns
- c) Between the first three numeric columns and final two columns in the
  sample data, there are text data: e.g., in row 1, columns V4:V10
  are all text, in    row2, V4:V6 are always text
- d)cells without  any
  data are blank
- e)the sample output must have the same first three columns as the sample data; the newcol1 in the sample output combine only text columns for that row
- f) the newcol2 and newcol3 in the sample    output are always the final two numeric values for each row (Note    again the column position differs across
  rows)

Please suggest only data.table solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
rowid_vars = c("V1","V2","V3")
melt(dt1, id=rowid_vars)[value!="", .(
  nc1 = paste(value[-(.N-1:0)], collapse=" "), 
  nc2 = as.integer(value[.N-1]), 
  nc3 = as.integer(value[.N])
), by=rowid_vars]


    V1 V2     V3                                   nc1 nc2 nc3
1: 301  1  61950 i believe we can use datatable always 500  32
2: 301  2  61951                        you think they 500  32
3: 301  3  61953                you are okay with that 500  32
4: 301  4 155220                              we laugh 490  31
5: 301  5 155218                            they smile 490  31
```

I guess there is some way you could have read in the data so as to avoid this problem, but I don't know how.